# Java Algorithm for finding shortest distance between 2d point and Matrix

Tags: java, distance, shortest

I'm stuck on this question for a couple of days now and would really like to get some help.

I am given a 2 dimensional point in the range of (0-1 not including 1), such as (0.5,0.2), and N other points (also in the range of 0-1).
The first part of the question is to implement the "dumb" algorithm, which when given a certain point will find the point with the shortest distance from it, which has a complexity of O(N).

The part I'm stuck at, requires to build a Matrix K on K, where each "cell" will contain the points that belong to that cell. Once done, when given the original point I will need to search for the point with the shortest distance to it only in some of the cells and not the entire Matrix, which should result better complexity.

My original thought is to devide the points so that each block will have an arraylist of points that belong to him, and then to somehow go through the main block(the one that the original point belongs to) and continue by going through it's neighbors, however implementing it hasn't been very successful.

I would highly appreciate any help/ advice.

Below is what I currently have:

```
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private Block b;
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public Point(double x, double y, Block b) //consrtuctor for complex case
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        b.points.add(this);
    }
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double distance(Point p)
    {
        double res=0;
        res = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x-p.getX(),2)+Math.pow(this.y-p.getY(),2));
        return res;

    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Block {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public ArrayList<Point> points;

    public Block(int x, int y) {

        points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}

import java.util.Random;


public class ComplexCase {
    private Block[][] blockMat;

    public ComplexCase(int k, int n)
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        Point p1;
        Block b1;
        double x,y;
        int bx1,by1;
        int t;
        t = 1/k;
        blockMat = new Block[k][k];
        for (int i =0;i<n;i++)
        {
            x = generator.nextDouble();
            y = generator.nextDouble();
            bx1 = (int) (x/t);
            by1 = (int) (y/t);
            b1 = new Block(bx1,by1);
            p1 = new Point(x,y,b1);
        }
    }
    public Block[][] getBlockMat() {
        return blockMat;
    }

    public void setBlockMat(Block[][] blockMat) {
        this.blockMat = blockMat;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: It's unclear what relevance the matrix has here.

Comment: Let me re-phrase please
The question has two parts:
The first part is to write the "dumb" algorithm, which when given a main point and an array of points will find the point with the shortest distance -> O(N).

The second part, is to use a matrix sized K on K which will divide the points into "blocks", and therefore to be able to scan only part of the matrix rather than all of the points, which will result better complexity.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Your problem appears to be a "choice" of algorithms. Check [Djikstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) or even any other combination of algorithms, such as [Divide and Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms), with [Voronoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)

Comment: You want to check every value in a matrix in better time than O(N)?

Comment: Without any additional assumptions, the runtime bound of `O(N)` where `N` is the number of points to check against cannot be improved, as the result depends on the entire input. Is it more like you are given a list of points which does not change (requiring some preprocessing) and you have to evaluate multiple queries for the single point, which however _does_ change?

Comment: The matrix has all of the points( say 10,000 points) divided in it. I need an algorithm that given 1 point will find the shortest distance to that point from another one in the matrix, by looking only in some if these blocks which will result better complexity

Comment: Are the entries in the matrix organized in some way?

Comment: No, In fact I need to construct the matrix myself, with N random points.

Comment: I've edited the original question, hopefully its more clear now, appreciate your help!

Comment: I think it would be better to refer to the "matrix" as a set of points, as it has nothing to do with matrices other than the coordinates form a matrix if the point coordinates are written on top o each other. Anyway, I think kd-trees, octtrees or AABB-trees are your friends here.

Comment: The thing with the matrix is that I need to run this multiple times (and measure the time it takes) and find the optimal K ( Size of matrix is K on K) which will result the best run time.

Comment: You cannot guarantee better performance with this algorithm. What if all the random points fall into the same cell?